# FFMPEG fade out image overlay issue on windows 10

Tags: ffmpeg, windows

sorry if my question is not exactly the correct format, this is my first post here

I have created  a ffmpeg one line code that will  fade in and fade out a transparent .png as a overlay

here is my code:

```
bin\ffmpeg -t 10 -i "video w bottom.mp4" -i "utube watermark.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.75*alpha(X,Y)',scale=150:150,zoompan=d=25*4:d=125:s=150x150,fade=in:st=2:d=1:alpha=1,fade=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1[im];[0][im]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,5)'" -c:a copy preview.mp4
```

now this works great!  BUT...  the issue i am having is if i try and change up the here:

`fade=out:st=4`  and `enable='between(t,0,5)`

then it no longer fades out correctly if say i change it to:

`fade=out:st=5`  and `enable='between(t,0,6)`

EDIT:
Here is the final code with with the info i got from @Gyan (I am sure can be cleaned up better)

```
SET /A overlayStart=2
SET /A overlayLength=6
SET /A fadeInDuration=1
SET /A fadeOutDuration=1
SET /A fps=30

SET /A startOverlayFadeIn=%overlayStart%
SET /A startOverlayFadeOut=%overlayStart%+%overlayLength%
SET /A betweenEnding=%startOverlayFadeOut%+%fadeInDuration%
SET /A overlayFullLength=%overlayStart%+%overlayLength%+%fadeInDuration%+%fadeOutDuration%
SET /A dur=%overlayFullLength%+4

bin\ffmpeg -t %dur% -i "video w bottom.mp4" -i "utube watermark.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.75*alpha(X,Y)',scale=150:150,zoompan=d=%fps%*%overlayFullLength%:s=150x150,fade=in:st=%startOverlayFadeIn%:d=%fadeInDuration%:alpha=1,fade=out:st=%startOverlayFadeOut%:d=%fadeOutDuration%:alpha=1 [im];[0][im]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,%dur%)'" -c:a copy preview.mp4
```

Hope this helps someone else out and/or they can expand on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In zoompan, you have set `d=125` so @ 25 fps, zoompan will create a 5-second stream.

Thus there are no frames after 5s for the fade to be applied to. The duration of the stream should be enough to cover the *end* of the fade transition. For `st=5:d=1`, total duration should be `5+1`=`6` or more.

Change to `d=150`.

P.S. In `d=25*4:d=125` the first `d=VALUE` is overridden by the 2nd one, so it is useless.

Comment: I will make a edit of the full code in the OP in case this can help someone else. Thank you

Comment: how can i set this up to run  by say 2-3 times?  from a variable i set of %c% times? do i need to ask a new question? @gyan